# Question about natural logarithm in the exponent of the e-function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I wonder which rule dictates that e^(-2x+ln(c)) is equal to e^(-2x) * c
I know that the logarithm naturalis is the "reverse-function" of the e-function but why isn't it e^(-2x) + c instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$ e^{-2x + \ln(c)} =  e^{-2x}e^{ \ln(c)} =e^{-2x}c$$

Comment: so the rule you are looking for is $e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$

Comment: ohh, thank you very much that makes it clear! :)